# Why won't my background Nav bar change colour?

Tags: html, css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am using the skeleton framework and am trying make a simple nave bar?

When I try and create a nav-bar div and set the css nav- bar id colour to blue the background won't change. However if i try and change the individual columns the colour will change. Is there a way will a grid framework to create a consistent nav bar on top with out telling each column to be a certain colour. this seems silly. 
Also is it possible to have a nav bar that extends past the frameworks 960px length? I would like to have the bar background extend to both sides of the screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="skeleton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
</head>
<div class="container">
    <div id="nav-bar">
        <div class="two columns">
            <h1>DS</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="nav" class="ten columns">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!---nav-bar--->
</div><!---container--->
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#nav-bar {
    background-color: blue;
}

#nav {
    margin: 13px 0 0 0;
}

#nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    margin-bottom: 130px;
}

#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black
}

#nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gp9d7yvz/

Comment: Can you add a fiddle please?

Comment: Well, regarding width... change skeleton.css, remove max-width from container, but you will have to set max-width for content in your custom css - if you want fixed width (in content section!).... So, you need custom layout/grid - make your own CSS, rather than using framework....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `#nav` children is floating left that make `#nav` has no height.
Let append `<div style="clear:both"></div>` before the closing tag of `#nav` to make it have height like this fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/gp9d7yvz/2/

Answer (score 0):

There is an error on the third line of your CSS code : there is no closing } tag. This causes the following CSS to malfunction. You also forgot to put the closing ";" at the end of your "color:black;" property. If it doesn't work also add a fiddle please.

Answer (score 0):

**First question:**
Try adding background-color under #nav not under #nav-bar

```
#nav {
margin: 13px 0 0 0;
background-color: blue;
}
```

**Second question:**
All your content is inside a .container with a width of 960px. You cannot get these div's to be 100% in width when they are inside this container. So what you need to is to change your code by moving the header outside of the container.

```
<div id="nav-bar"> 
      <div class="two columns">
            <h1>DS</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="nav" class="ten columns">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div><!---nav-bar-->


<div class="container">
</div><!---container-->
```

Here is an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/gp9d7yvz/5/

[When using grid 960, can I still have a 100% width header section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766959/when-using-grid-960-can-i-still-have-a-100-width-header-section)

Comment: Try not to post links to content without including the relevant parts here as that linked page could be removed later