# Grid 960 take up entire width with resize

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

I am having trouble getting my 960.gs to take up the entire width of the browser. I want the grid to be 100% on resize, that is if I scroll out the text will appear smaller and take up less lines but the grid will still take 100% of the width.

There is this question here [When using grid 960, can I still have a 100% width header section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766959/when-using-grid-960-can-i-still-have-a-100-width-header-section) And the answer was to set the top part to 100%. I added the code but this has no effect, neither does setting the body's width to 100% and all divs, ect. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>My Fragment</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <!-- Symbols rendered -->
        <meta name="value" />
        <!-- Do not need to close -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/960_12_col.css">
        <style>
            body {
                background:green;
            }
            div {
                background: white;
            }
            .grid_4 {
                height: 100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="header" style="width:100%;"></div>
        <div class="mainWrapper container_12">
            <div class="grid_4" style="background:red">sdfds</div>
            <div class="grid_4" style="background:blue">sdfs</div>
            <div class="grid_4" style="background:yellow">sdfs</div>
            <div class="clear">sdfds</div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

But this gives me the following result:

[image]

I want to see no green space on left side of the red column and the right side of the yellow column but this is not the case. How do I get rid of the space either side?

(Please note I am new to css and Html and have been following the learn html in 30 days, and whatever else I find online.)

Comment: Could you provide demo?

Comment: Demo? Ahhh... like do you mean some html code of what I've done, with a picture of the output, and an explanation what is wrong with it? Like whats in the question?

Comment: Yep, because when I insert your code to jsfiddle, I got different result with image in question

Comment: You need to have the 960_12_col.css contents. You don't need to use jsfiddle, as there is no javascript. You can just use the browser to open the html locally.

Comment: I inserted to jsfiddle 960_12_col.css  from GitHub and code didn't work like on image:(

Comment: Lol your suppose to be helping me not the other way around. On my computer I have index.html with the contents I posted, and then a folder css where 960_12_col.css is located, you would have to copy the contents into a style tag, such as the one I have where the body is styled, if you want to use jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - `<div class="header" style="width:100%;"></div>` is not wrapping your container.

Second: add `width: 100%` to your `mainWrapper` class instead of `.header`, but that i know there is hardcoded widths in 960 grid system, so your columns with `.grid_4` will be still `width: 300px`.

Try with another Grid System with fluid layouts, e.g.: http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/

Comment: So the widths are hard coded for grid960 ? There is no way to have resizeable columns?

Comment: Yep, look here: http://960.gs/css/master.min.css - there are `.grid_4 { width: 300px; }`, `.grid_5 { width:380px; }`, etc... Use another grid system, like http://unsemantic.com/ or http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Thank you but I'm sad that it won't resize my components, I just wasted heaps of time ) :

Comment: Replace your 960.css file with this one: http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/css/grid.css - it is fluid version of 960.gs

Comment: THANKYOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! That did it, awesome awesome. Can't upvote you more than once sorry.